# How to calculate the ground state of bosonic hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, ground-state

I am trying to find the ground state of the Hamiltonian:

$H=\sum^N_{K=i}\omega_kb_k^\dagger b_k$ where $b_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum^N_{N=i}\exp(\frac{2\pi ikn}{N})b_n$.

Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: That Hamiltonian is already diagonalized.  The eigenstates are the collective eigenstates of the number operators $N_k=b^{\dagger}_kb_k$. What exactly are you trying to do?  I assume that $b_n$ should be something like $a_n$, in the sense that they are different lowering operators that populate different states.  Perhaps you are trying to write the eigenstates in terms of the eigenstates of $a^{\dagger}_na_n$? Can you clarify?

Comment: If this was fermionic would you know what to do?

Comment: need to clean up your summation limits to clarify your sums.